# Testing report not generated using ZAP in jenkins free style job

Tags: zap

I have created a Freestyle project in Jenkins with installed ZAP plugin to find the security vulnerabilities in our hosting web applications. Job has been configured with below steps followed,

https://dev.to/gwllmnn/automatic-security-tests-in-jenkins-with-owasp-zap-2f6b

Job has been built properly also job got success but testing report generated as empty.  An error occurred like this while navigate the testing report,

```
HTTP ERROR 404

Problem accessing /job/Check-OWASP%20ZAP- 
FreeStyle/Vulnerability_20Report/Jenkins_ZAP_Test_Report.html. Reason:

Not Found
Powered by Jetty:// 9.4.z-SNAPSHOT
```

Could you please provide a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and it is fixed by upgrading jenkins , its was a bug https://jenkins.io/changelog-stable/

Comment: This answer isn't really helpful if you don't link to the specific bug, or at least specify in which version of Jenkins it was fixed.